# Why use multiple hyphens for WebVTT cue?

Tags: html5-video, caption, webvtt

I'm looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API.

The pertinent example is this:

```
WEBVTT - This file has cues.

14
00:01:14.815 --> 00:01:18.114
- What?
- Where are we now?

15
00:01:18.171 --> 00:01:20.991
- This is big bat country.

16
00:01:21.058 --> 00:01:23.868
- [ Bats Screeching ]
- They won't get in your hair. They're after the bugs.
```

I do not understand why I would do `They won't get in your hair. They're after the bugs` in one hyphen vs doing something like:

```
- [ Bats Screeching ]
- They won't get in your hair.
- They're after the bugs.
```

Does the original mean it will split into two title cards vs three in that same timeframe? If that's the case, why not break it into more cues instead of one cue with more hyphens? Or is it meant to have multiple lines in the title card, all shown at once?

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed a player each dash is a new line:

```
00:01.000 --> 00:10.000
- It will do something.
- It will do another thing.
```

[image]

So it's up to engineer to decide what is a good sentence length and if you want multiple lines or not.